# Mechanize uploading image returns 403 error

Tags: python, python-requests

i am trying to upload a image to ebay-kleinanzeigen.de with mechanize, but everytime i try it, i am getting a 403 error.

The code for the login:

```
import mechanicalsoup

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.set_user_agent(
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36')

a = browser.open('https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/m-einloggen.html')
browser.select_form('#login-form')
# browser.get_current_form().print_summary()
browser['loginMail'] = 'testaccount@8.dnsabr.com'
browser['password'] = 'testaccount'
browser.submit_selected()
```

Select category where to list the product:

```
response = browser.open(
    'https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/p-anzeige-aufgeben.html#?path=161/173/motorola_handy&isParent=false')
crsf = response.soup.find('input', {'name': '_csrf'})['value']

payload_select_category = {"_csrf": crsf,
                           "parentCategoryId": "210",
                           "categoryId": "223",
                           "attributeMap[autoteile_reifen.art_s]": "ersatz_reparaturteile"}

response = browser.post('https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/p-anzeige-aufgeben-schritt2.html', payload_select_category)
```

upload image:

```
img_file = open(r'C:/Users/Oli/Google Drive/IMG_20190616_153432.jpg', 'rb')

payload_img_upload = {'name': 'Image.jpg'}

file = {'name': 'Image.jpg',
        'file': ('Image.jpg', img_file, 'image/jpeg')}

response = browser.post('https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/p-bild-hochladen.html', payload_img_upload, files=file)
```

By the way, the login data i provided here is working.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code:

```
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36'}
header['content-type'] = 'text/html'

base_url = 'https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de/'

session = requests.session()
res = BeautifulSoup(session.get(f'{base_url}m-einloggen.html').content, 'lxml')
csrf_token = res.find('input', {'name': '_csrf'})['value']
print(f'Found token: {csrf_token}')

payload = dict()
payload['targetUrl'] = '/'
payload['loginMail'] = 'testaccount@8.dnsabr.com'
payload['password'] = 'testaccount'
payload['_csrf'] = csrf_token
payload['fingerprint'] = '4dd6ba9367ddc34f0b00cf9566e01b63'

res = session.post(f'{base_url}m-einloggen.html', data=payload, allow_redirects=True)
print(f'Logged in: {res.status_code}')

img_file = open(r'C:/Users/Oli/Google Drive/IMG_20190616_153432.jpg', 'rb')
files = {'name': 'TestImg.jpg', 'file': ('TestImg.jpg', img_file, 'image/jpeg', {'Expires': '10'})}

header['content-type'] = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----moxieboundary1563218428568'
header['x-csrf-token'] = csrf_token
res = session.post(f'{base_url}p-bild-hochladen.html',headers = header, files=files)
print(f'Image uploaded: {res.status_code}')
```

Also, there is this encoding. The Image is being uploaded in a certain encoded way, can you tell me which encoding is this. I think this is the issue:

[image].

Comment: Thank you for help Nitin! The response is showing me now 200, but there is a error message in the content which tells me in german i shouldn't choose empty image.

Comment: I did not check that. Will let you know if I find any solution.

Comment: I don't know which encoding it is. Base64 is also the wrong, i hope i will find the correct encoding.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is: ISO 8859-9, but i dont how to encode the image to this encoding