# How do I convert this cURL code to python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, curl

So I have this example from https://www.file.io/

```
$ curl -F "file=@test.txt" https://file.io
```

How do I use this in python? I tried this:

```
from requests import post
from urllib import request
from base64 import b64encode

with open('files/some_name.mp4', 'rb') as img:
                encoded_img = b64encode(img.read())
        r = post(url='https://file.io', data={'file' : encoded_img})
        r = r.json()
        print(r)
```

And got `{'success': False, 'error': 400, 'message': 'Trouble uploading file'}`

Comment: this page can conver `curl` to python and other languages: https://curl.trillworks.com/

Comment: why do you encode file ? Send it as normal data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not send the file in the `data` parameter.
There is a `files` parameter, try using that.

```
file = {'file': ('image.mp4', encoded_img)}
r = post(url='https://file.io', files=file)
```

Check this if it works. also refer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57037841/send-binary-image-by-post-request/57042336#57042336)

Comment: Thanks, the thing was easier than I thought

Answer (score 0):

Using this portal https://curl.trillworks.com I got working code. I tested with some image.

```
import requests

files = {
    'file': ('test.txt', open('test.txt', 'rb')),
}

response = requests.post('https://file.io/', files=files)

pritn(response.json())
```